# TI Microcontroller Programming Circuit

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, programming, texas-instruments

I am working on designing a pcb that will contain a TI TM4C1231D5PZ microcontroller. I have only ever used a launchpad before for coding, so I do not know how to get my program code onto a microcontroller that is going to be on a pcb. I have looked at multiple resources, including the datasheet, and I can't find a circuit or even an understandable explanation of how to put the program code onto the microcontroller. I believe that I have all of the software complete and working, but I just need to get it on to the microcontroller. How is this process accomplished? Are there any helpful resources that explain this process?

Comment: There are many ways. A common one would be to use the JTAG interface.

Comment: It's been a while for me on the TI TMS MCUs, but I believe they are programmed in-circuit via the JTAG interface as @Tyler mentioned.  In fact the needed lines are brought to pins on the Launchpad which you can connect to a MCU in-circuit and do programming for prototypes and small production.  For large scale production the distributor can often program them for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always a good idea to add a JTAG interface for in-circuit debugging.

There are various debug probes you can choose from. The XDS100v2 is fairly cheap, if you can get a hold on one (TI doesn't distribute this anymore).
Another good option is the XDS110 ([PDF](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sprui94/sprui94.pdf) / [Product Page](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/xdsdebugprobes/emu_xds110.html)).
You can even use the LaunchPad as debug probe. See SPMA075 (referenced below), chapter 4.6.

And on the PCB you have to add a JTAG header (e.g. ARM 10-pin header):
[image]

For more info, check the Application Report SPMA075: [Using TM4C12x Devices Over JTAG Interface](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spma075/spma075.pdf).

---

For production, where you **only** need to program the TM4C, you can use the integrated Boot Loader (ROM).

The TM4C1231D5PZ supports UART0, SSI0, I2C0 and USB. Check the [Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c1231d5pz.pdf) chapter 8.2.2.1 Boot Loader Overview.
Also check the [TivaWare Boot Loader User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu301e/spmu301e.pdf).

As PC tools you can either use [LM Flash Programmer](https://www.ti.com/tool/LMFLASHPROGRAMMER) or [Uniflash](https://www.ti.com/tool/UNIFLASH).